# How do I download data from Github to my local machine using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

I cloned a project from Github, and ran `rake db: create & migrate`. The database is created but the contents of the tables are missing.

Is there a way I can pull the data from Github to my local machine also?

Comment: Typically the convention is not to upload the actual database file into Github. As such, whenever you clone a project from Github, you will have to create and start with a new database. If you want to populate it, you can either use the seeds.rb file or find another way to get data into the database.

Comment: where the data on github account are resided?

Comment: When you clone a repo, you get an exact copy of the project, hence the name "clone". So, you already have all what you could have downloaded.

Comment: As a side note, you should use rake `db:schema:load` when you import a project, not `migrate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have created the database with `rake db:migrate`, there will be no data in the tables by default. To do this, you can either [write a custom script](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) (as others recommend in a db/seeds.rb file) or just run `bundle exec rails console` and create some stuff in the database manually by doing things like:
`User.create!(name: 'PowerCoder')`

At this point, you may be tempted to add the database to Git so that you don't have to do this again. **Resist the temptation!**
Adding your database.sqlite3 file to version control is a bad idea for a couple reasons:

1. it is a binary file, which causes Git agony because it cannot compress or diff versions of it
2. it updates frequently - any time you do just about *anything* in your development environment
3. it will allow anyone with read access to the repository access to see all your (possibly private) data

Answer (score 1):

If there are no seeds in the project (db/seeds.rb) or instructions in the Readme or DB dumps in repo there is not much you can do apart from populating it by yourself.